# Inflate Exception #14: Binary XML file line #17: - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragment, excepciones

Mi app no se puede ni siquiera abrir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me arroja este error que no puedo comprender:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.OptiApp/com.example.OptiApp.Activities.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class item
```

XML que marca error:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Activities.Main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigationdrawer"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_options"
    />
```

No tengo ninguna clase llamada item.
Cualquier aporte sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: muestra el archivo xml

Comment: @armen listo, ya agregué el XML de error

Answer (score 1):

La InflateException no es realmente el problema, pero en realidad proviene de otro problema más profundo en su diseño que luego se envuelve en una InflateException. Un problema común es una excepción de memoria insuficiente cuando se intenta inflar una vista de imagen cargando un recurso dibujable. Si uno de estos recursos tiene una resolución de píxeles alta, se necesitaría mucha memoria, lo que provocaría una excepción inflada.

Básicamente, verifique que la resolución de píxeles en sus imágenes dibujables sea el mínimo necesario para su diseño.